# Pandas - finding the row with least value of one of the levels of a multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I have a DataFrame with a multiindex which looks like this:

```
                               info1 info2       info3
abc-8182 2012-05-08 10:00:00       1   6.0     "yeah!"
         2012-05-08 10:01:00       2  25.0        ":("
pli-9230 2012-05-08 11:00:00       1  30.0  "see yah!"    
         2012-05-08 11:15:00       1  30.0  "see yah!"    

...
```

The index is an id and a datetime representing when that info about that id was recorded. What we needed to do was to find, for each id, the earliest record. We tried a lot of options from the dataframe methods but we ended up doing it by looping through the DataFrame:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(...)
empty = pandas.DataFrame()
ids = df.index.get_level_values(0)
for id in ids:
    minDate  = df.xs(id).index.min()
    row = df.xs(id).xs(minDate)
    mindf = pandas.DataFrame(row).transpose()
    mindf.index = pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(id, mindate)])
    empty = empty.append(mindf)

print empty.groupby(lambda x : x).first()
```

Which gives me:

```
                                               x0  x1        x2
('abc-8182', <Timestamp: 2012-05-08 10:00:00>)  1   6     yeah!
('pli-9230', <Timestamp: 2012-05-08 11:00:00>)  1  30  see yah!
```

I feel that there must be a simple, "pandas idiomatic", very immediate way to do this without looping though the data frame like this. Is there? :)

Thanks.

Comment: If your data is already sorted in time as indicated here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788777/pandas-how-to-eliminate-duplicates-in-the-index] - then drop_duplicates selects 'first' of the duplicate rows automatically

Comment: I must pass the columns to drop the duplicates, right? But the duplicates I wanna drop are in one of the levels of an index, not as a column.

Comment: I did `df['id'] = df.index.get_level_values(0)` than `df.drop_duplicates('id')` works. It's a lot better, but it still feels hackish.

Comment: df.reset_index() would insert the index values as columns. But I agree the answer below seems 'more' correct

Comment: This does exactly what I need: `df2.reset_index().set_index('id').sort('datetime').groupby(lambda x : x).agg(lambda x : x[0])`

Comment: df2.reset_index().groupby('id').first() - is a little more clearer should give the same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the first item in each group, you can do:

```
df.reset_index(level=1).groupby(level=0).first()
```

which will drop the datetime field to a column before the groups are grouped by groupby, therefore it will remain in the dataframe in the result.

If you need to ensure the earliest time is kept, you can sort, before you call `first`:

```
df.reset_index(level=1).sort_index(by="datetime").groupby(level=0).first()
```

Comment: You're kidding me it's that simple!! Hahaha. Even if the dates aren't sorted? Is there a way to sort them?

Comment: I tried this but it just returned the exact same dataframe. If I do `df.sort().groupby(level=[0]).first()` it kinds of does what I want, but I loose the date information, which is needed for my purposes.

Comment: If you have a MultiIndex where level 0 has values like 'abc-8182' and level 1 has timeseries values, then the above code should drop that duplicate row and keep the first in your example.  You're saying that's not happening?

Comment: Nope. Inspecting the result of the groupby, I have a single item in each group. It seems that grouping by both levels should result in this, given that each index entry is unique (there's only one datetime per id).

Comment: In the above example you have a duplicate index.  I think we are looking at different dataframes.  Grouping by both indexes will certainly only contain one item in each group if each index is unique.  So if that's the case, group by level=0 instead if that is your desired result.  Sorry if I'm misunderstanding what you are after.

Comment: Perhaps this is what you want instead? `df.sort().groupby(level=0).first()`

Comment: Sorry! I pasted the wrong dataframe. That one was for another question (the question linked above, about getting rid of duplicates in the index). As I said before, this solves my problem, but I loose track of the datetime information (the id becomes the sole new index after the groupby). Not all th first items have the same datetime, and I need this information too.